# Compizconfig unmet dependencies

Tags: dependencies, configuration-management

I have an error since upgrading ubuntu to 16.04 and I can't do anything on my pc. It only shows the desktop picture, I searched for problems and someone said that I have to install compizconfig-settings manger but it says that some packages have unmet dependencies and 4 packets appear on the screen  and some are not installable and some re to be installed and I don't know what to do. I tried installing the packages seperatly with '-f' and after I installed the first one, it disappeared from the list, I installed the second one and the first one appeared again.What should I do?! (Sorry if my english is bad)

Comment: Can you state the 4 packages that needs to be installed and the screenshot of your PC?

Comment: Please always [edit] your question to provide new important information.

Comment: These are the packages and this is what it says:       Compizconfig-settings-manager depends on python-compizconfig (>=1:0.9.12.2+16.4.20160823-0ubuntu1) but it's not going to be installed. Gstreamer1.0-clutter depends on libcogl15 (>=1.15.8) but it's not installable. Libnux-4.0-0 depends on libsigc++-2.0-0c2a (>=2.0.2)but it's not installable. Librsvg2-common depends on Librsvg2-2 (2.40.13-3) but 2.40.2-1 is to be installed